# Continuity via sequence

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function .Suppose there are sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $x_n<0<y_n$ for all $n \ge 1$ and $f(y_n)-f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty $.Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$

Here as for is increasing hence the sequences must converge to same limit and by sequential criteria of continuity we get that if f has to be continuous at 0 then every sequence f (xn) goes to 0 similarly for yn but  I am not being able to show that both the sequences f (xn) and f (yn) tends to 0 when xn,yn goes to 0 
Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is not continuous at $0$, then either there exists some sequence $(c_{n})$, $0<c_{n}<y_{n}$ such that $f(c_{n})$ does not converge to $f(0)$ or there exists some sequence $(d_{n})$, $x_{n}<d_{n}<0$ with the same property. Without loss of generality, we pick such a $(c_{n})$. We can further assume that $c_{n}<y_{n}$. Now $x_{n}<0<c_{n}<y_{n}$ implies $0\leq f(c_{n})-f(x_{n})\leq f(y_{n})-f(x_{n})$, $0\leq f(y_{n})-f(0)\leq f(y_{n})-f(x_{n})$, so $f(c_{n})-f(x_{n})\rightarrow 0$, $f(y_{n})-f(0)\rightarrow 0$, then so is $f(c_{n})-f(0)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: The construction is the key point of the proof.